# GeoServer s3-geotiff module with custom S3 provider fails

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, geotools

I'd like to use the s3-geotiff module within GeoServer with a custom provider (Minio).
The minio server is running properly and I could reach the tiffs in the bucket from a variety of s3 tools.

Following the instructions of the [docs](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/s3-geotiff/index.html) I've created a s3.properties file with endpoint, username and password strings.

I've placed the s3.properties file in the root of Geoserver_Data dir and also in the security folder.
Unfortunately, using the s3 buckets tiff as a datastore fails. Geoserver always wants to reach the bucket on an AWS S3 instance. Using AWS, everything works as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a custom S3 provider, the s3.properties file path must be included via java system properties. So attaching `-Ds3.properties.location=/opt/geoserver_data/s3.properties` to my `JAVA_OPTS` within my docker build did the trick

Comment: Do you know where this is documented?

Comment: I was interested in the documentation to find out if I could put environment variables in the `s3.properties`. I have learned this is a generic Java configuration file format and that it does not evaluate environment references. [To work around that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64281927/3003133), I have the file dynamically created by setenv for Apache Tomcat.