# GeoServer: Properties are missing! S3GeoTiff

Tags: geoserver

I am using GeoServer 2.17 on windows and installed the geoserver community module "S3GeoTiff" to use .tiff image hosted on Amazon S3.

When I start the server in the command prompt I receive this warning/error:

```
01 dic 16:57:55 INFO [geoserver.config] - Initiated CatalogTimeStampUpdater
dic 01, 2019 4:57:56 PM org.geotools.s3.geotiff.S3GeoTiffFormat <init>
GRAVE: Properties are missing! The system property 's3.properties.location' should be set and contain the path to the s3.properties file.
```

I am quite a bit lost on what to do, I created an s3.properties file with the stuff needed inside already, but I don't know how to set a system property.
The docs of the module just say what to put in the s3.properties file, not how to set this s3.properties.location thing.

Comment: how you set environment variables depends heavily on what operating system you are using and how you installed GeoServer. Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: Similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/310436/26375

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my particular case I missed setting this string:

```
-Ds3.properties.location=<<path to s3.properties file>>
```

in my startup.sh in the bin folder in geoserver install dir.

Comment: Do you know where the documentation is for this?

Comment: I was interested in the documentation to find out if I could put environment variables in the `s3.properties`. I have learned this is a generic Java configuration file format and that it does not evaluate environment references. [To work around that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64281927/3003133), I have the file dynamically created by setenv for Apache Tomcat.